# aws sdk php for listing s3 folders

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

few things I do know.
Folders are not a concept of S3 they are merely a zero byte object with key names that use the '/' as prefixes. Assuming that we call them folders and files for simplicity would make my question easier to phrase.

It is possible to do a s3->get_object_list(..) with prefix ="root/" and get all the files/folders. My problem is this.

Given a list of folders and subfolders for e.g.

```
root/  
root/folder1/  
root/folder1/file1.txt  
root/folder2/ 
root/folder3/file2.txt
```

How can i list only the folders. I was hoping to prevent listing all files (even in response they need not be returned) but get_object_list in php does not current support commonPrefixes ref: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/get_object_list
even though the doc says so the code clearly does not and using the delimiter will actually only return files in the root folder (prefix)

I am wondering if anyone has used any technique post-response or request based to help with such a situation.

I have already tried every combo of prefix,delimiter and marker i could think of. Not so good with PCRE but sure I could use that I only have one level deep folders but I don't know how to construct one for this case. Since my requests were not working I proceeded to accept the response with all files and folders and hopefully sort it out in php... or so I thought

I have tried in post response:
dirname() - no use misses out some folders (empty ones), sure I can remove duplicates in array but the problem of missed folder exists
pathinfo() - behaves the same way as dirname(), assumes that all paths end with filename.
glob - no luck, same as above.

Since I have already wasted half a day on this I am hoping someone has dealt with this and would care to share:

note: I have no problem doing this in python and boto. But this is not python and I have to do this in PHP for this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've confused `get_object_list()` with `list_objects()`. See: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=106277&tstart=0